# Nodejs https get response not working

Tags: node.js

i have a hundred of `PNG` files and i need to compress their sizes, i found a page that can make the compression ([tinypng](https://tinypng.com/)).

so i made a node program that will retrieve the name of each file inside a folder and then stream them

```
var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");

var path = '../';
var compressedPath = path + 'conversion/';
var key = '<api key>';

var options = require("url").parse("https://api.tinypng.com/shrink");
options.auth = "api:" + key;
options.method = "POST";

var file = fs.readdirSync(path);

console.log('files loaded');

for(data in file)
{
    if(file[data].indexOf('gif') == -1 && file[data].indexOf('png') != -1)
    {
        // console.log(path + file[data]);

        var input = fs.createReadStream(path + file[data]);
        var output = fs.createWriteStream(compressedPath + file[data]);

        var request = https.request(options, function(response)
        {
            if(response.statusCode == 201)
            {
                https.get(response.headers.location, function(response)
                {
                    response.pipe(output);
                    console.log(file[data] + ' compression success');
                });
            }

            else
            {
                console.log(file[data] + ' compression failed');
            }
        });

        input.pipe(request);
    }
}
```

i make a log on the get in order to see that it is working properly, but it does not show anything, even outside the get function, and when i check the folder where i the downloaded files will be, they are already in there, but in 0kb size, no data inside them, and i does not even get any error..

i'm new at node and this will be my first time making upload responses with node, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you always get a 201 on success? What status codes do you get for each request?

Comment: @mscdex i get 201 on every file

Comment: What `statusCode` does the `https.get()` callback receive? Does `response.on('data',function(d){console.dir(d.toString('binary'))})` show binary data in the console when placed inside the `https.get()` callback?

Comment: @mscdex it gets nothing, i tried writing `response.on('data',function(d){console.dir(d.toString('binary'))})` inside `http.get()`

Comment: What does `console.log(response.statusCode, response.headers)` show inside the `https.get()` callback?

Comment: @mscdex still, nothing is shown in the console, i really don't get why it does not work.

Comment: Did you check `response.headers.location` to make sure it starts with `https://`? If it starts with `http://` instead, you need to use `http.get()`, not `https.get()`.

Comment: @mscdex yes, the response starts with https and provides the url of the data i need to recieve